# Line by line data from Google cloud vision API OCR

Tags: python, pdf, ocr, google-cloud-vision

I have scanned PDFs (image based) of bank statements.
Google vision API is able to detect the text pretty accurately but it returns blocks of text and I need line by line text (bank transactions).
Any idea how to go about it?

Comment: Do the blocks contain newline symbols, e.g. '\n'?

Comment: yes. Also, I have the words and the coordinates of bounding boxes.

Answer (score 6):

I have used Google Vision API - DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION for getting the line by line data.
The data which is returned has the following structure:
*The structure might change for different APIs.*

```
{
   'description': 'Some Text',
   'coordinates': [ P1, P2, P3, P4]
}
```

The approach I used was calculating the mid-point of all the words.

```
{
   'description': 'Some Text',
   'center': { x: (P1.x + P2.x + P3.x + P4.x)/4, 
               y: (P1.y + P2.y + P3.y + P4.y)/4 }
}
```

Now I sorted these words on the basis of their center coordinates. In both X and Y axis. 
But for sorting in Y-Coordinates you will need some Y-Tolerance Variable.

For example,

```
word_1.center.y = 15
word_2.center.y = 18
word_3.center.y = 28
```

Now, you have to decide how much difference in Y-Coordinate value is needed to change lines (which depends upon the font-size used in the document).

```
(word_2.center.y - word_1.center.y) < Y-Tolerance # True ~ In same line
(word_3.center.y - word_2.center.y) < Y-Tolerance # False ~ In different line
```

After you get the list of words in the same line. Sort them according to their X-Coordinates.

Please reach out in case of any other query.

Comment: **Clustering**, tedious but likely the only solution.

Comment: A better approach instead of using a "Y-Tolerance" is to calculate the min and max Y-Point and check if the range of word_2 is in the range of word_1 and vice versa. If so => line Merge.  With the Y_Tolerance you may experience an issue when pictures are not horizontal enough.

Comment: Fair point @MarkusG.but the issue is that the font size may vary throughout the page. Hence min and max for Y-Point may fluctuate to a great extent.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Vision API there is a method `fullTextAnnotation` which returns a full text string with `\n` specifying the end of the line, You can try that.